# How to create and add video to a youtube playlist with video url?

Tags: python, youtube

I have a list of links to YouTube videos such as

```
"https://youtu.be/########"
"https://youtu.be/########"
```

How can I create a YouTube playlist and add those videos to it using Python?

I have tried using Selenium, but it would be nice to do this without opening a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution using selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='geckodriver')
## signin with youtube before continue

driver.get("## your youtube link")
add_playlist_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('ytd-button-renderer.ytd-menu-renderer:nth-child(4) > a:nth-child(1) > yt-icon-button:nth-child(1) > button:nth-child(1)')
add_playlist_button.click()
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkboxContainer"]')[1].click()
```

This will add the video to your last created playlist